# Remove a relationship from index with APOC Neo4J 3.x

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

when I remove a relationship in Neo4J 3.x I want it also to be removed from the automatic index created using APOC.

However, I don't see any procedure to remove a relationship in APOC. I only see `removeRelationshipByName` but then I have to specify the Name of the relationship and what if I had the relationships by type? If the relationship is not deleted, I get an error when I try to search using this index by relationship property. It finds a relationship in the index but it doesn't exist.

Just to get a better idea, I created the index on existing relationships using

`MATCH ()-[r]->() CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['user','context','statement','gapscan']) RETURN count(*);`

This creates several indexes for several relationship types.

I also set up a trigger so that every time a relationship is added (no matter what type) it is added to the index of the appropriate type

`CALL apoc.trigger.add('RELATIONSHIP_INDEX',"UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r MATCH ()-[r]->() CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['user','context','statement','gapscan']) RETURN count(*)", {phase:'after'})`

Now, what I want to do is to set up a trigger that would remove the relationships from the index when they are removed. But there's no procedure `removeRelationship` — only `removeRelationshipByName` — however, I don't understand how to use it in that context. What name should I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation / example for `apoc.index.addRelationship()`:

> The statement will create the relationship index with the same name as relationship-type.

This is the name of the relationship index, and the name to provide to `removeRelationshipByName()`.

The naming on this particular procedure is rather confusing...the `ByName` part refers to the relationship index, not the relationship itself.

Comment: Thank you, but then it means I cannot just remove the relationship from all the indexes? Have to make a separate request for each, right?

Comment: Since a relationship can only have a single type, and since `addRelationship()` only adds each relationship to a single index, there should only be one index to remove the relationship from (its type).

Comment: In fact addRelationship() creates an index for each type of relationship, so I can run a trigger with a single query to update the desired properties in each of the indexes for each type of relationship (as above). however, i can’t seem to do that for when I remove a relationship — then i have to set up a trigger for each type of relationship it looks like...